# the store() controller is not working in laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel

i am working on crating a post for my blog app. laravel 5.7 . but when i want to create a new post it dose not redarect to the index page of the post ...it is just refresh the crate page .......i don't know why its not working .......here is my create blade page

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="card card-defualt">
    <div class="card-header"> Create post</div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <form action="{{route('posts.store')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" name="Title" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="description">Description</label>
                <textarea name="description" id="description" cols="5" rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="content">Content</label>
                <textarea name="content" id="content" cols="5" rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="published_at">Published At</label>
                <input type="text" name="published_at" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="image">Image</label>
                <input type="file" name="image" id="image" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create post</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

@endsection
```

and  post controller

```
 public function store(createpostrequest $request)
    {
        $image=$request->image->store('posts');
        post::create([
            'title'=>$request->title,
            'description'=>$request->description,
            'content'=>$request->content,
            'image'=>$image
        ]);

        //flashing the message

        session()->flash('success','catagory created successfully');
        return redirect(route('posts.index'));
    }
```

and here is the request

```
    {
        return [
            //
            'title'=>'required|unique:posts',
            'description'=>'required',
            'content'=>'required',
            'image'=>'required|image'
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Your form could be failing because you have the name as `name="Title"`, but you're validating against `title`. You're not showing [the errors](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#the-at-error-directive) at all on the blade, so it's hard to tell. You can do some logging inside of your store function with `Log::info(__LINE__);` along the way to see exactly where the code is hitting. All logging will go into a file in `/storage/logs`

Comment: there is no error ....when i cliked the 'create post' button its just refersh the page and come with the crate page itself thats why am not showing the errors .......and also i name to 'title' but it dosent work still

Comment: By error, I mean validation errors. If it hits a validation error, it will go back to the form, but it won't *throw* an error, it just puts a MessageBag in the session. Read the link I provided to see how to show the validation errors.

Comment: i also used that you provided in the link but is dosen`t work ................i remove all in the controller and i just use ''dd($request->image)" method but is also didn't work !!

Comment: Do you have ```$fillable``` property in model

Comment: yes here it is ...```namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class post extends Model
{
    //
     protected $fillable = [
        'title','description','content','image','published_at'
    ];
}```

Comment: can you show how you defined route `posts.store`

Comment: Your form contains `<input type="text" name="Title" class="form-control">` where name is starting with capital letter and in your controller you used small letter while fetching title. so change form input to `<input type="text" name="title" class="form-control">`